# Updating custom rules in SCOM when moving to new version of Active Directory

Tags: scom

We are currently in the process of upgrading our Active Directory environment from 2012 to 2016.

As such we have several custom rules setup within SCOM to alert on changes to certain AD groups.

These rules have been setup in SCOM to target 'Active Directory Domain Controller Server 2012 R2 Computer Role'

Is there any way to edit these rules to now target the 'Active Directory Domain Controller Server 2016 Computer Role'

IF not is there a way to copy rules which would allow me to recreate them easily whilst changing the target.

Additionally should there be another Target I pick in order that when we do upgrade to AD 2019 I don't need to re-visit this task.

Answer (score 0):

if you run the following PowerShell command, it will show you all versioned DC role classes and their first parents:

```
Get-SCOMClass -DisplayName "*Domain Controller Server * Computer Role" | ForEach-Object { Write-Output "$($_.DisplayName) => $($_.Base.Identifier.Path)" }
```

My output looks like:

```
Active Directory Domain Controller Server 2016 Computer Role => Microsoft.Windows.Server.AD.Library.DomainControllerRole
Active Directory Domain Controller Server 2012 R2 Computer Role => Microsoft.Windows.Server.AD.Library.DomainControllerRole
Active Directory Domain Controller Server 2000 Computer Role => Microsoft.Windows.Server.AD.DomainControllerRole
Active Directory Domain Controller Server 2008 Computer Role => Microsoft.Windows.Server.AD.DomainControllerRole
Active Directory Domain Controller Server 2012 Computer Role => Microsoft.Windows.Server.AD.Library.DomainControllerRole
Active Directory Domain Controller Server 2003 Computer Role => Microsoft.Windows.Server.AD.DomainControllerRole
```

So, 2008 DC and below based on `Microsoft.Windows.Server.AD.DomainControllerRole`, but above is based on `Microsoft.Windows.Server.AD.Library.DomainControllerRole`. Presumably, you don't need older versions, so your target should be `Microsoft.Windows.Server.AD.Library.DomainControllerRole`, unless MS changes the inheritance path again.

Next, how to change your rules. It's not possible to change target in SCOM Console, even if rule's management pack is not sealed. However, if your MP is not sealed, you can:

1. Export your MP as XML.
2. Change reference from the current versioned MP to the library (Microsoft.Windows.Server.AD.Class.Library).
3. Replace all current targets.
4. Import the MP back.

Your new reference should be like (run `Get-SCOMManagementPack -Name Microsoft.Windows.Server.AD.Class.Library` to verify to your environment).

```
<Reference Alias="MPAlias">
        <ID>Microsoft.Windows.Server.AD.Class.Library</ID>
        <Version>10.0.2.1</Version>
        <PublicKeyToken>31bf3856ad364e35</PublicKeyToken>
      </Reference>
```

Then your rules' targets should be like:

```
<Rule ID="your_ID" Target="MPAlias!Microsoft.Windows.Server.AD.Library.DomainControllerRole"
```